# ip address blocking

Tags: c#, sockets

I have one server and client application using socket programming in c#. In this, max. 10 clients can be connected to the server at a time. But my requirement is that I have to block one of the clients via IP address when i'm sending messages through server.. Please help with blocking. The program is given below..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class SocketServer : Form
    {
        const int MAX_CLIENTS = 10;

        public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
        private Socket m_mainSocket;
        private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[10];
        private int m_clientCount = 0;
        private byte[] byData;


        public SocketServer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBoxIP.Text = GetIP();
        }

        String GetIP()
        {
            String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            // Find host by name
            IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

            // Grab the first IP addresses
            String IPStr = "";
            foreach (IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
            {
                IPStr = ipaddress.ToString();
                ip = IPStr;
                return IPStr;
            }
                 ip = IPStr;
                return IPStr;

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonStartListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Check the port value
                if (textBoxPort.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Port Number");
                    return;
                }
                string portStr = textBoxPort.Text;
                int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
                // Create the listening socket...
                m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                          SocketType.Stream,
                                          ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);


                    // Bind to local IP Address...
                    m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
                    // Start listening...
                    m_mainSocket.Listen(4);
                    // Create the call back for any client connections...
                    m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);

                    UpdateControls(true);

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateControls(bool listening)
        {
            buttonStartListen.Enabled = !listening;
            buttonStopListen.Enabled = listening;
        }

        public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string message, object obj);

        public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                // Here we complete/end the BeginAccept() asynchronous call
                // by calling EndAccept() - which returns the reference to
                // a new Socket object
                m_workerSocket[m_clientCount] = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);
                // Let the worker Socket do the further processing for the 
                // just connected client
                WaitForData(m_workerSocket[m_clientCount]);
                // Now increment the client count
                ++m_clientCount;
                // Display this client connection as a status message on the GUI    
                String str = String.Format("Client # {0} connected", m_clientCount);

                //textBoxMsg.Text = str;
                textBoxMsg.BeginInvoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { str, textBoxMsg });

                // Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
                // other clients who are attempting to connect
                m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);


            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }

        private void UpdateText(string message, object ctrl)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
                textBoxMsg.Text = message;

            if(ctrl is RichTextBox)
                richTextBoxReceivedMsg.AppendText(message);
        }

        public class SocketPacket
        {
            public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
            public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1];
        }

        public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                {
                    // Specify the call back function which is to be 
                    // invoked when there is any write activity by the 
                    // connected client
                    pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;
                // Start receiving any data written by the connected client
                // asynchronously
                soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,
                                   theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                   SocketFlags.None,
                                   pfnWorkerCallBack,
                                   theSocPkt);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }

        }

        public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

                int iRx = 0;
                // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
                // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
                // by the client
                iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
                                         0, iRx, chars, 0);
                System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
                //richTextBoxReceivedMsg.AppendText(szData);
                richTextBoxReceivedMsg.BeginInvoke(new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), new object[] { szData, richTextBoxReceivedMsg });

                // Continue the waiting for data on the Socket
                WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }
        private void buttonStopListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloseSockets();
            UpdateControls(false);
        }

        void CloseSockets()
        {
            if (m_mainSocket != null)
            {
                m_mainSocket.Close();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m_clientCount; i++)
            {
                if (m_workerSocket[i] != null)
                {
                    m_workerSocket[i].Close();
                    m_workerSocket[i] = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                Object objData = richTextBoxSendMsg.Text;
                byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < m_clientCount; i++)
                {
                    if (m_workerSocket[i] != null)
                    {
                        if (m_workerSocket[i].Connected)
                        {

                                m_workerSocket[i].Send(byData);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Minimize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
            {
                Hide();
                this.notify.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.notify.Visible = false;

        }
```

Comment: Your question really isn't clear.  Please clarify what specifically you need to do, when -- and what you've tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: My requirement is that I can block one of the client that i wish. Maximum 10 clients can be connected to the server. When I am sending messages to the clients, the blocked client won't accept the messages that i sent from the server. Have you got it my idea?

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat easy to do, you just need to look a little more at the client connection routine...  Replace the 127.0.0.1 below with the IP address you want to deny and throw an exception or simply close the connection and return.

```
public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
        if (clientEndPoint.Address == new IPAddress("127.0.0.1"))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
```